# My secondary monitor gets a lot hotter than my main monitor. can I mitigate this without buying a new monitor?

Tags: multiple-monitors, cooling, lcd

I have 2 monitors: An LG E2241 and a Fujitsu Siemens H22-1W. I use the LG monitor as a main display for all my games (because it's 1080P) and the H22-1W as a secondary display that just about only shows Chrome (because the 1680 by 1050 resolution frequently isn't supported by games).

The LG monitor is 4 years old and still works fine. The H22-1W, however, is starting to show some issues. Today, while rearranging my power setup for easier access to free power outlets, I had trouble turning the screen on again multiple times after turning it off and moving the plug to another outlet (as some people in Root Access chat probably noticed). I managed to get it working again after a few minutes of rearranging cables, but it was still concerning.

The H22 is quite old by now, about 8 years, and I've found that the edges are getting quite hot after a few hours. I don't have a specific temperature reading, but they're so hot that I can feel the heat from over a foot away (30 cm) and the screen itself feels less like an LCD screen and more like the inside of a car after it's been in the sun for a while. It's not so hot that it hurts to the touch, but it gets noticeably hotter than the other monitor, which only feels warmer on one side, and I think it's indirectly, through heat transfer from the other monitor, because the other edge doesn't suffer from warmth.

I've tried googling this, and I can't really find any mention of other people having this issue. I'm worried that this excess heat might be indicative of more serious issues. Can I reduce this excess heat amount without buying a new monitor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I imagine that your heat concerns are based on the power consumption between the models.  Your LG monitor consumes 24 watts nominal and your Fujitsu up to 60 watts.  It's also an older monitor, like you've mentioned, so it's reasonable to assume it's using power transfer technology that is more wasteful.

LG specs:

> http://www.lg.com/us/commercial/lcd-computer-monitors/lg-E2241VB-BN

Fujitsu specs (PDF):

> http://pdfstream.manualsonline.com/d/d214af74-64eb-4d1a-984c-2b0be9612433.pdf

Comment: I pressed "post" too soon and forgot to ask the question I was actually looking to ask. I edited my question to amend this.

Comment: According to the operating manual, the monitor does have a power saving mode, but it's simply suspended (no input) with no display.  Even in that mode, it draws nearly ten times the amount of power that your LG monitor does when it's in suspend.  There doesn't appear to be any other power-saving mode features available for that model.  Additionally, since the monitor is using LCD technology, it contains a back-lighting bulb component that is always on and does not have a dimming feature, so there is no hope that using dark screens or contrasts will help power consumption.

Comment: is that 60 watts per hour?

Comment: Yes.  Wattage is a measurement that already includes time (typically hours).  Therefore that's 60 watts per hour.